# php listing mysql data in html table in columns and rows

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have 2 tables in my database, player and score table. I have data in these table and want to list the data from my score table to a HTML Table. I want the player names to be the columns and the scores of the players to be the rows. I have seen examples of how to add rows with predefined columns, but haven't seen examples on how to add set the data as columns. Since player name is in player table I will have to use join function to display the player name, not sure how to do this with php. I am new to php, so have been stuck at this for a while.

> Database

**Player table:**

```
playerid
name
lastname
```

**score table:**

```
scoreid
score
playerid (foreign key with player.playerid)
```

My score data contains ex:

```
scoreid: 1, score: 53, playerid: 1
scoreid: 2, score: 23, playerid: 1 
scoreid: 3, score: 12, playerid: 2 
scoreid: 4, score: 67, playerid: 3 
scoreid: 5, score: 31, playerid: 2
```

> PHP:
>   This is what I have working for now but it only displays the name.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM player");

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

> Wanted Result

```
| Jonny  |  Mike  |  Bill  |
|   23   |   10   |   12   |
|   12   |   31   |   23   |
```

..etc

As you can see the player names are the columns and scores are the data in rows corresponding to the player.

Think of it like:

**Player table has:**

```
id: 1. name: Jonny
id: 2. name: Mike
id: 3. name: Bill
```

**score table has:**

```
scoreid: 1, score: 23, playerid: 1 (Jonny)
scoreid: 2, score: 12, playerid: 1 (Jonny)
scoreid: 3, score: 10, playerid: 2 (Mike)
scoreid: 4, score: 31, playerid: 2 (Mike)
scoreid: 5, score: 12, playerid: 3 (Bill)
scoreid: 6, score: 23, playerid: 3 (Bill)
```

Hopefully you get a better understanding now

> Output

This is how it looked before

[image]

This is how the result looks now:

[image]

Comment: So could you please give an example how your table should look like?

Do you want the scores of the player to be new columns beside the players name? Or do you want them to be displayed row by row?

Comment: Just updated my question showing wanted result

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get where the given data belongs to - you used 2, 3, 1, 12, 12 and 23 - but these are not all scores of the player in this column?!

Comment: I have updated my question once again showing in better detail, As you can see Jonny has score 23 and 12, Mike has 10 and 31 etc.  These are the scores of the corresponding players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do get your table displaying "row-data in columns" is to use a table in a table, since you **have to** build a table in HTML row by row.

Then, to get all scores of a player, you can either request the data for each player by a seperate request or use a GROUP_CONCAT.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT p.*, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.score) FROM score s WHERE s.playerid = p.playerid) AS scorearray FROM player p");
```

Now your result will contain all colums of your player table and a column "scorearray", which contains a comma-separated list of all scores from your player. [See GROUP_CONCAT example](http://blogs.interdose.com/dominik/2008/01/11/group_concat/).

To generate the first row you can reuse your given code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT p.*, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.score) FROM score s WHERE s.playerid = p.playerid) AS scorearray FROM player p");


$playercols = array(); 
$scores = array(); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $playercols[] =  "<th>" . $row['name'] . "</th>"; 
    $currentscore = explode(",", $row['scorearray']); 
    // Only doing a line break, you can build a one-columned table out of this data aswell 
    $scores[] = "<td valign=top>" . implode("<br />", $currentscore) . "</td>"; 
} 
echo "<table>"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo implode("", $playercols); 
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo implode("", $scores); 
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "</table>";
```

See the result here: [Result](http://stackoverflow.dev.lbader.de/36990107/result.php)

And full source here: [Source](http://stackoverflow.dev.lbader.de/36990107/source.php)

Comment: This code doesnt seem to work for some reason. I have edited my $result & change my table content to the code you provided and even tried to echo "<table> and </table> in the end & tried without having <table>. I dont get no output. Could you show a example with <table> or am I not suppose to use it?

Comment: What is `t.playerid` just wondering where you defined what `t` is I see you have `score s` but nothing for `t`, could you explain what that means? The code is in  `WHERE s.playerid = t.playerid`

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be a typo. I meant `p.playerid` instead of `t.playerid` which is defined in `FROM player p`

Comment: What do you mean by "getting no output"? Do you have error reporting turned on? Then please give the error message.
I could not test this code, maybe there are some typos / wrong syntax.

Comment: After I changed t.playerid to p.playerid. I get results. But the output doesnt look like how I expected `Bill GatesJohnSteve JobsMike55
50
5522
50
70
2250
100
30
22
2220
22
22
70
30`

I will update my question with how it looks, so you can see better

Comment: I have update my main question showing the results, can you check it out

Comment: Actually, the code i posted works. I just added a table-tag to it.

I created the database on my server and made called the script.

See the result here:
http://stackoverflow.dev.lbader.de/36990107/result.php

And the source here:
http://stackoverflow.dev.lbader.de/36990107/source.php

Comment: Awesome, tried it with your new code and it works. Thanks

Comment: I do have one question, guessing it easy to do but is it possible to add the game number as the first column, the rows for game number are just the game number, ex: first row in "game number" is 1, 2nd row is 2..etc. The idea is first row is the scores of the first round of the game..

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `JOIN`, along the lines of:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT player.*, score.* FROM player LEFT JOIN score ON score.playerid = player.playerid ");

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Score</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if its possible to make the player name as the columns? and display the scores as the rows for the player? Tried searching for an example of this for a while with no success. I have edited my question showing the wanted result