# sorting the id in ascending order by the value of index_no - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-update

I want to change my id according to the index value.

Here is an example of how my `score table` in my database looks

[image]
`player_id` is a foreign key connected to player table. As you can see the `id` is not ordered by my `index_no`

**I want this result:**

[image]

How can I do this in php so it sorts my database accordingly? Im guessing I have to loopthorugh the array and use UPDATE function, since I'm new to php, I'm having a hard time doing this.

Comment: Why don't use mysql ORDER BY instruction when retrieving data?

Comment: order by index_no asc

Comment: Could you show be an example of how to do it, so if I run the query on mysql once in the database, is it enough and the database will do the job till I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You should order it:

```
SELECT * FROM score
ORDER BY player_id ASC, index_no ASC
```

Enjoy it. :-)

Comment: I need to change the id aswell, the just sorts the table

Comment: Why do you want to change it? it's needless to get what you want.

Comment: I need it because I am listing the scores in a html table, and the scores gets listed by id, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990107/php-listing-mysql-data-in-html-table-in-columns-and-rows/36991053#36991053)

Comment: This sorts only the `index_number` and not sorting it compared to `playerid`